# Excel sheet Deletes the formulas present in the sheet when I open it. How to avoid this?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm uploading an excel file that contains sheets, to my server which encodes to base 64 so I decode it as required and process it by adding data in sheet 5 as column1 and column2 with certain number of rows. At the time of uploading, this sheet has some specific formulas on sheet 5 that makes changes in other sheets. So on opening the file which I send as response after editing from server, There comes this prompt that reads

"Excel Found unreadable content in 'MyDownloadedExcelData.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes', with Yes and no buttons

and when I click on yes and open the sheet, all the formulas are deleted.

I see something like

Excel was able to open the file by repairing ot removing the unreadable content.

Removed Records :Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml Part 
Repaired Records : Cell Information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part etc

So, How do I make sure my formulas in the sheet are retained?

Comment: If you save the file to your computer, do you have the same problem?

Comment: If the file saves/restores OK without the encoding, I suggest you add `base64` tab to your question.  There is likely an issue with how your server is encoding/decoding the document.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for the response. I download the file on my computer and when I open it up, I see the error I mentioned. When I open the sheet after clicking yes on prompts, only when I double click each formula cell the formula gets re applied and gets me the result in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA you could have an on close event that pastes values and an on open event that recreates the formulas. Your file would essentially save with static data, but then be used with functions intact.

If this solution is of interest I can help provide some coding framework.